# Firing named functions from an array with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

I'm very new to JavaScript, but this topic seems to have attracted only scant forum attention. Given a number of simple functions:

```
function do_something(){...};
function do_somemore(){...};
function do_something_else(){...};
```

I was expecting to be able to assign these explicitly to cells in an (here 2D) array.

```
myMatrix[5][3] = do_something();
myMatrix[5][4] = do_somemore();
myMatrix[5][5] = do_something_else();
```

The reason I want to use such an approach are :

1. simple to understand and maintain.
2. eliminates potentially redundant anonymous function assignments in the array.
3. any given function can be assigned to multiple array cells, for example:

   ```
   myMatrix[2][6] = do_somemore();
   myMatrix[5][4] = do_somemore();
   myMatrix[6][3] = do_somemore();
   ```

Unfortunately, calls such as the following (based on various forum examples, plus a little "suck it and see") are all failing.

```
x = myMatrix[5][4]do_somemore();         -> "missing ; before statement"
x = (myMatrix[5][4])do_somemore();       -> "missing ; before statement"
x = (myMatrix[5][4]do_somemore)();       -> "missing ) in parenthetical"
x = (myMatrix[5][4])(do_somemore());     -> "is not a function"
x = (myMatrix[5][4])()do_somemore();     -> "missing ; before statement"
x = myMatrix[5][4]()do_somemore();       -> "missing ; before statement"
x = myMatrix[5][4]();                    -> "is not a function"
x = (myMatrix[5][4])();                  -> "is not a function"
```

As I have no knowledge of JavaScript internals, I'd be glad of suggestions how to get the function calls *firing*.

Comment: Many thanks to everyone who contributed insights. The code was working correctly within a couple of minutes assigning as follows:

myMatrix[5][4] = do_somemore;

..and then calling using myMatrix[left][right]();

The former I'd already tried, but the latter had escaped me :-)

Comment: Please consider selecting an answer or add more specific information if none of the answers satisfy your question.

Answer (score 2):

You should assign them like this:

```
myMatrix[5][3] = do_something;
```

Comment: Indeed. At the moment, the OP is *calling* the functions and assigning the returned values to the matrix.

Comment: And the correct syntax to call such a function is `x = myMatrix[5][3]();`. Also notice that those parentheses are called ‘function call operator’.

Answer (score 0):

```
myMatrix[5][3] = do_something;
```

Your way would set the value to the RESULT of the function!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely clear about what you are after, but:

First, before you can assign a value to an array, that array has to exist:

```
var myMatrix = [];
myMatrix[5] = [];
myMatrix[5][3] = … // Then you can assign something
```

Then, if you want to assign the **return value** of a function:

```
myMatrix[5][3] = do_something();
```

Or, if you want to assign **the function itself**:

```
myMatrix[5][3] = do_something;
```

… and then call it and assign its return value to `x`:

```
var x = myMatrix[5][3]();
```

… which is the same as `var x = do_something()` except that inside the function `this` will be `myMatrix[5]` instead of `window`.

Answer (score 0):

```
myMatrix[5][3] = do_something; 
myMatrix[5][4] = do_somemore; 
myMatrix[5][5] = do_something_else; 


var x = myMatrix[5][3]();
var y = myMatrix[5][4]();
var z = myMatrix[5][5]();
```